# App fullscreen with UI statusbar

Tags: android

I want to make app fullscreen with transpirent status bars i use below code but it only show app in fullscreen but not showing status bars

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {


        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                          |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN

                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
getWindow.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
```

and also You can set own Status color

```
 getWindow.setStatusBaroColor(YOUR_COLOR):
```